# Are there any side effects with adding a method to a declerative class in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I had asked this question [How to create instance of a table entry but not added in ponyorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111070/how-to-create-instance-of-a-table-entry-but-not-added-in-ponyorm) where I was asking how I can create an instance of the class defined as a ponyorm table representation without immediately adding it. By using sqlalchemy where an explicit `add` is needed on a `session` instance I think I succeeded by using the following code.

I first create a class called `AddInstance` which has an add method, and then inherit from this in all my table definitions. This seems to work (ie I can create an instance of the class and add it only if I want to relatively easily)  but I'm not sure if there are any unintended side effects or this is very far from best practice.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine                                               
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base                         
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship                           
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer                                  


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')                                    
Base = declarative_base()                                                       
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)                                                


class AddInstance:                                                                 

    def add(self):                                                              
        session = Session()                                                        
        session.add(self)                                                       
        session.commit()


class Pizza(Base, AddInstance):                                                    
    __tablename__ = 'pizzas'                                                       
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                         
    name = Column(String(50))                                                      
    toppings = relationship('Topping', back_populates='name')                      


class Topping(Base, AddInstance):                                                  
    __tablename__ = 'fruits'                                                       
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                         
    name = Column(String(50))                                                      
    pizzas = relationship('Pizza', back_populates='name')                          


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no side effects, SQLAlchemy explicitly supports adding methods. It doesn't matter if those methods are defined on a mixin class or directly on the class derived from `Base`.

Quoting from the [SQLAlchemy *Object Relational Tutorial* documentation section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping):

> Outside of what the mapping process does to our class, the class remains otherwise mostly a normal Python class, **to which we can define any number of ordinary attributes and methods needed by our application.**

(*bold emphasis mine*).

There are plenty of examples of code bases that do exactly the same. Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a `Model` base class to [add a `query` attribute](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py#L143-L146) (set when the [declarative base is created](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/500e732dd1b975a56ab06a46bd1a20a21e682262/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L764-L765)), which lets you do `Topping.query(...)` directly from a model class, for example.

Your `add()` method does have downside: it creates a new `Session()` instance just to add and commit your object. This keeps it outside of the normal [session state management semantics](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html) and if you wanted to do *anything else* with your newly created object you'd have to [merge it into an existing session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging).

The normal, best practice for code involvig SQLAlchemy objects is to create a session to manage a *transaction*, a set of operations that together must succeed or fail. That includes creating objects; in many real-world applications you'd want to avoid creating extra rows in a database when other operations that rely on those rows fail. Your `.add()` method unconditionally commits each object in a separate transaction. You may want to revisit this pattern.

Comment: when you say they need together to succeed or fail, is that for example if you have a `Pizza` and `Topping` table and you need to commit the new Pizza with the new Topping at the same time or fail together otherwise you might end up with a `Pizza` referencing (or trying to reference) a `Topping` that doesn't exist or vice versa?

Comment: @evan54: exactly. While foreign key constraints can help avoid such issues to some extend, real-life applications usually require more related changes that you'd want to commit together or roll back if something fails that would leave the database in an inconsistent state.